# How to debug in Zend Studio with Mod_Rewrite?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-studio

I am working on a PHP web project and want to debug it locally. The website is designed with `mod_rewrite` such that a request to `www.mysite.com` is rewritten to `www.mysite.com/fitch/index.php?cmd=home`.

Zend Studio requires me to select a file when I attempt to debug my project.

Here is a screenshot of my workspace:
[image: Workspace]

When I right-click on wxbell (in PHP explorer) and go to `Debug As >> PHP Web Application`, I am presented with the following screen:
[image: Debug Project]

Here I must specify a file to debug. I cannot enter `/`. So what do I do? How do I debug the  project without selecting index.php directly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to debug without the mod_rewrite?? (asked here because I dont see an option to add a comment).

If you are then maybe there may be some issues with mod_rewrite(dont have much experience to say more about that, end of post for you right here :) ).

but in case you are not able to debug any application, here are a few sources where you may get some information about debugging(I myself struggled for hours to get a zend project debugged)

This one explains debugging in zend studio.Helped me with the mapping correctly i.e server links to local files.
http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=421

this one however is not concerned with zend studio but explains debugging with Eclipse(so mostly similar).Explains debugging concept with a little more clarity.

http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/

And for your question about the file to be selected, I dont think it matters as  I tried changing the file paths(choosing diff. files) but the result was the same(it debugged :)).

Note:xdebug used for debugging and the debugging options were set in the debug configuration.(inside Run menu in ZS 9)

Hope you get it working.